# Ms access : calculated field from other table

Tags: ms-access

I've been searching for this for a while and I can't seem to find anything!

Here's my problem: 
I have a ms access database for the maintenance of the trucks of a company.
I've built a form in which you can see a VEHICLE and the amount of money spent on it. This information is available by a subform that takes information in the MAINTENANCE table

I would like to have the same exact information in the VEHICLE table so I could build charts (histograms) 
basically I want a calculated field in my VEHICLE table that reads the MAINTENANCE table and sums up every maintenance for this vehicle.

I hope this is not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Its not impossible.  However, you may need to rethink how you want to do this.

You could do this in C# or VBA, etc, but since I'm not an expert at those, I'll give you a simple solution.

1. Create the maintenace_total field in your vehicle table.
2. Create a new table (tbl_VehicleMaintenanceAmt) that only contains the fields for your unique vehicle identifier and maintenance total.
3. Create a new query (qry_AppendVehicleMaintenanceAmt) based on your maintenance table that groups by vehicle unique identifier and sums the maintenance amounts.
4. Change your new query (qry_AppendVehicleMaintenanceAmt) to append to your new table (tbl_VehicleMaintenanceAmt).  This will give you a clean one row per vehicle with maintenance total.
5. Create a new update query that links your new table (tbl_VehicleMaintenanceAmt) with your Vehicle table by vehicle identifier, and update the maintenance_total in your Vehicle table with the Maintenance amount from tbl_VehicleMaintenanceAmt.

You'd want to clear out the tbl_VehicleMaintenanceAmt and re-append your maintenance total data to it every time you want to get accurate numbers.

You could also do this with Form and Subform grouping with Sums and Totals, but the explanation is a pain so I went as far as I'm willing.  :)